# Angular 17 - Mat Tab not rendering Mat Table rows

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table, mat-tab

I am using latest Angular version in my project.
In my component I have a Mat-Tab-Group with a Mat-Tab. Inside this tab I want to display a table component that I have created by myself. This component is able to show a table content. This component is working and rendering correctly, when using outside of the Mat-Tab!
When placing it inside you can see the issue clearly: When setting the animationDuration to a larger value, and switching to the tab my table component is inside, the table rows are not being rendered. When switching back to another tab, the rows appear while the tab is animating to the other tab.

I was searching for this issue but couldn't find anything related.
Do you know more about this issue? Is it an known issue or a new issue for the latest version of Angular?

Comment: Instead of describing your code, _show it to us_. See [ask].